# Access Terraform Cloud environment variable

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to figure out Terraform Cloud, just wondering how I would access environment variables I've set in the workspace within my files?

```
// main.tf

// Configure the Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
  credentials = "GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS"
  project     = "my-project"
  region      = "australia-southeast1"
}
```

I've set an environment variable on the cloud workspace `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` with the value being my .json key formatted to work with TFC.

Just not sure how to access it within my `main.tf` file like above

Comment: According to the documentation, environment variables you place in TF Cloud are exported on the ephemeral machine that it remotely executes on. Are you executing this locally?

Comment: Typically when using environment variables to configure a provider you don't refer to them in the configuration at all. Instead, you omit the options in the `provider` block and let the provider read the environment variables itself. That approach is recommended over direct configuration of the provider because it gives the most flexibility to potentially run the same configuration in other contexts later, if you e.g. move away from Terraform Cloud, or if you are working locally for development purposes with a personal set of credentials.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I figured that would be the case, like as I would do it locally. I have it working now, but I'll try omitting the variable in the file and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add credentials to the Terraform Cloud environment variable `TF_VAR_credentials` and set it as sensitive. then you can use the variable here :

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = var.credentials
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
}
```

and declare your variable  like this

```
variable "credentials" {
  description = "credentials"
}

variable "project" {
  description = "project"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "region"
}
```

then on the apply command you can pass :

```
terraform apply \
    -var "region=${REGION_FROM_ENV}" \
    -var "project=${PROJECT_FROM_ENV}" \
    -var "credentials=${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS}"
```

here's a reference :
https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#var-39-foo-bar-39-

Comment: If I am doing this from Terraform Cloud though? I did the above and it seems to autocomplete the last step

Comment: @Ari  yes ${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS}  will look in the env variable so if it dosn't found the variable the param will be passed as an empty string make sure you set the env variable before the apply like :
export GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS="your_credentials"